# Go Test delete logger.SetLogging log file

Tags: go

I have a TestCase for a function that defines a log file path, then sets logger, so that `log.*` statements are written to standard out and the log file:

```
lf, err := os.Create(logFile)
mw := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, lf)
log.SetOutput(mw)
```

In my Test case I'm attempting to cleanup at the end, but it appears there is a lock on the file still, which means the Os.Remove() call is not working (or even returning an error)

I've tried to SetOutput to nil as well as using a defer statement.

```
func TestSetLogging(t *testing.T) {
// do stuff
...
log.Println("this should be in logger file")

// cleanup
log.SetOutput(nil)
defer os.Remove(logFile)
}
```

Yet, the logFile still appears on disk. How can I delete this file?

Comment: You shouldn't have a defer call at the end of the function. Are you exiting the test early in the `// do stuff`? Maybe post all your code to make things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling:

```
lf.Close()
```

before

```
os.Remove(logFile)
```

or you can replace

```
defer os.Remove(logFile)
```

with:

```
defer func() {
  lf.Close()
  os.Remove(logFile)
}()
```

Comment: I see.  hmm unfortunately the file was created in a function and lf is out of scope.   It does explain why it's happening though.

Comment: I modified the function that sets logging to also return the *os.File handle.  Then used your suggestion, but I had to reverse the order for the defer statements:   defer os.Remove(logFile); defer lf.Close()

Comment: You have to close file handle before removing the file. The file will not really be deleted until the last handle is closed.